# How to generate the needed SQL statements to Update, Insert, Delete data in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, sqldatasource

I'm using `GridView` along with `SqlDataSource`, for **selecting**, **updating** and **deleting**,
and `DetailsView` for **Inserting**, the problem is, when I click one of these buttons, I get this error for the `Delete` order (and the same error with `Insert` and `Update`..):

> Deleting is not supported by data source 'SqlDataSource1' unless
>   DeleteCommand is specified.

it is very exhausting to add these statements myself, and in some cases I need to define stored procedures. I'm asking because I read(but not remember where, unfortunately) a tutorial, which Visual Studio generate all these automatically.

source code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Donor.aspx.cs" Inherits="Donor" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
         AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
         DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
         EmptyDataText="There are no data records to display." 
         ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" AllowSorting="True">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" ShowEditButton="True" ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="Name"  ItemStyle-Width="150px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="BloodGroup" HeaderText="BloodGroup" SortExpression="BloodGroup"  ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Disease" HeaderText="Disease" SortExpression="Disease"  ItemStyle-Width="120px"/>
        </Columns>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
         SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [BloodGroup], [Disease], [Id] FROM [Patient]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" CellPadding="4" 
         DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" ForeColor="#333333" 
         GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="125px" 
         DefaultMode="Insert">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#FFFFC0" Font-Bold="True" />
        <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#FFFF99" Font-Bold="True" />
        <Fields>
            <asp:CommandField ShowInsertButton="True" />
        </Fields>
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Name], [BloodGroup], [Disease] FROM [Patient]" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Patient] ([Name],[BloodGroup],[Disease]) VALUES (@Name, @BloodGroup, @Disease)">
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Name" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="BloodGroup" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Disease" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code what you've did?

Comment: See in SQLdatasource1 contains Selectcommand only, You've to include the all other commands(insert,update,delete) as like as @user2946329 Answer.

Comment: Couldn't this accomplished automatically by just enabling insert, delete and update for SqlDataSouce?

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf...You could also do this by click on the **Configure Data Source** in your `SqlDataSource`.

Comment: @MohammedElshawaf...As I said: To make ASP.NET generate the DELETE command automatically for you without any code you should use *Configure Data Source*. I Updated my answer with a full *walkthrough*.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `DeleteCommand` to your `SqlDataSource`:

```
DeleteCommand="Delete from yourTable WHERE (ID = @ID)"
```

Like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" DeleteCommand="Delete from yourTable WHERE (ID = @ID)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="ID"></asp:Parameter>
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**EDIT:** To make ASP.NET generate the `DELETE` command automatically for you without any code do the following steps:

1. In the tasks window of your `SqlDataSource`, click **Configure Data Source**.
2. Choose your data connection and **Next**.
3. Make sure *Specify a custom SQL statement or stored procedure* checked and click **Next**.
4. Select **DELETE** Tab and then click on the **Query Builder**, Select your table and then build your query by helping the *Query Builder* window. Your query should be look like this finally:

   ```
   Delete from yourTable WHERE (ID = @ID)
   ```
5. And finally click **Next** And **Finish**.