# Deleting a row when the user presses delete button

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

This might be a easy problem but i don't see what i'm doing wrong here. The code is:

```
 protected void dgvSelected_RowCommand (object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName =="Delete")
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.CommandArgument.ToString()))
            {
                int RowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
                dgvSelected.DeleteRow(RowIndex);


                dgvSelected.DataBind();
            }


        }
    }
```

And at the end of the class i have this method.

```
protected void dgvSelected_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

I'm using asp .net and i have a gridview that several rows and at each row i have a delete button where the user can press it to delete the row. For the moment when i press the delete button the whole gridview disappears. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate the needed SQL statements to Update, Insert, Delete data in GridView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34529385/how-to-generate-the-needed-sql-statements-to-update-insert-delete-data-in-grid)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
protected void dgvSelected_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    dgvSelected.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the gridview data was from antoher gridview, the solution was to make a viewstate variable and save the datatable in it. And then to delete one row:

```
protected void dgvSelected_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = Convert.ToInt32(e.RowIndex);
        DataTable dt = ViewState["SelectedValue"] as DataTable;
        dt.Rows[index].Delete();
        ViewState["SelectedValue"] = dt;
        dgvSelected.DataSource = dt;
        dgvSelected.DataBind();
    }
```