# Delete row from aspnet gridView via column button

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

I want to delete a row from an aspnet table, that have columnButton with [delete] button.

This is my code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridInduccionPersona" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="RUT" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" DeleteMethod="GridInduccionPersona_RowDeleting">
       <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
       <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="RUT" HeaderText="Rut" InsertVisible="False"
```

.
.
.

```
           **<asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Delete" HeaderText="Eliminar" ShowHeader="True" Text="Eliminar" />**
       </Columns>

   </asp:GridView>
```

but when I put the page on Chrome; said: ***The Select operation is not supported unless you specify SelectMethod.***

I just want to acces to function in server, and delete from gridview and database.
I dont want to use linq or similar, Im working with stored procedure.

Any idea about that ? is SelectMethod important for delete from my column ? (I supposed that the button call the id, or some similar in gridview to delete)

Comment: https://weblogs.asp.net/anasghanem/solving-the-select-operation-is-not-supported-by-unless-the-selectmethod-is-specified

Comment: This might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/34529434/2946329

Comment: is not working that solution, I put in the gridView `DefaultMode="Insert" AutoGenerateRows="False"` but doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember from ASP.net Webforms, the GridView needs the SelectMethod property configured to works properly.

`SelectMethod` should point to the method that obtains the records.

Without this property, GridView can't list the records, so you can't delete them.

So, set the SelectMethod property to target to the method that retrieves the records.

Comment: I just want to put a button in the rows to delete; any alternative ? with that aspnet button ? or another via to make it ?; my problem is that datasource is from a stored procedure; so I dont need to work via linq or similar. Just need to see the data, and delete from the list

Comment: OK, but regardless of your datasource type. You need to configure the SelectMethod property for GridView works.

So, assuming you have a method called `GetData` that gets the data through the stored procedure, do `'SelectMethod ="GetData"`

This will cause the error _"The Select operation is not supported, unless you specify SelectMethod "_ disappear.

The rest of your ASPX seems to be correct.